# PHP Simple IP Logger format

Tags: php, date, logging, time, ip

I have made simple PHP IP logger and need some help. Right now, I have set it to grab IP and make new line, ready to log the next (I have to use HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP instead of REMOTE_ADDR because I'm on cloudflare). What I want to know is: how do I make it show this format instead of just IP: IP date time. I want all three of those not just IP each separated by space.
~~Thank you

```
<?php
  $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"];
  $file = "ip.txt";
  $txtfile = fopen($file, "a");
  fwrite($txtfile, $ip."\n");
  fclose($txtfile);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate ip with result get by [`date`](http://php.net/date) function:

```
$ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"];
$file = "ip.txt";
$txtfile = fopen($file, "a");
// here:
$line = $ip . " " . date("d.m.Y H:i:s");
// for your required format:
$line = $ip . " | " . date("d.m.Y | H:i:s");
// write $line instead of $ip to a file
fwrite($txtfile, $line . "\n");
fclose($txtfile);
```

Comment: Thanks, what if i want format to be like: 127.0.0.1 | 25.10.2015 | 05:53:36

Comment: Thanks again. Also, what would be proper place to put this in my html? like what tag? or should i keep it outside of the html tag

Comment: You can put each line in `<p>`, or `<span>` or `<li>` of a `<ul>`. That's a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
<?php {
$date = fopen("thefile.txt","a+"); //open log file
    fwrite($date, date("Y-m-d H:i:s ")); //writes date and time
    fclose($date); //closes the file
                
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; //get supposed IP
    $handle = fopen("thefile.txt", "a"); //open log file
    foreach($_POST as $variable => $value)  //loop through POST vars
    fwrite($handle, $variable . "+" . $value . "\r\n");
    fwrite($handle, "$ip\r\n"); //writes down IP address and adds new line
    fclose($handle); //close the file
    }
?>
```

You will see this on the the file.txt:

```
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

I mean with numbers not alphabets like this `2021-01-01 24:59:59 *someones ip address*`, every time the website gets load it will write down the date, time and IP address and new line as seen up here.
NOTE: This will not show on the loaded websties `view-source:https://expamle.com` cause this script will execute server site, if your hosted website supports it. You can also mess around with it

Comment: You can also add your desired format to the date as seen on this website:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_format.asp